# Python threding requests count

Tags: python-3.x

When i run this code its show me

```
1     Hello world

2     Hello world

3     Hello world

4     Hello world

5     Hello world

6     Hello world

7     Hello world

8     Hello world

9     Hello world

10     Hello world

1     Hello world

2     Hello world

3     Hello world

4     Hello world

5     Hello world

6     Hello world

7     Hello world

8     Hello world

9     Hello world

10     Hello world

1     Hello world

2     Hello world

3     Hello world

4     Hello world

5     Hello world

6     Hello world

7     Hello world

8     Hello world

9     Hello world

10     Hello world

[Program finished]
```

How can i count 1 to 20 not 1 to 10 tow times

```py
from threading import Thread

def test():
    for i in range(10):
        print(str(i+1)+"     Hello world")
    
t1=Thread(target=test)
t2=Thread(target=test)

t1.start()

t2.start()
```

Comment: Change the number from `range(10)` to `range(20)` and only run one thread?

Comment: Then it will work normaly i want to add more then 5 Thred

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter to your `Thread` objects to act as a per-thread offset:

```py
def test(offset):
    for i in range(10):
        print(str(offset + i + 1) + "    Hello world")

t1 = Thread(test, args=(0,))
t2 = Thread(test, args=(10,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

*How can i count 1 to 20 not 1 to 10 tow times*

Use a single Thread with a range of 20 ...

```
>>> def test():
...     for i in range(20):
...         print(str(i+1)+"     Hello world")
...
>>> t1=Thread(target=test)
>>> t1.start()
1     Hello world
2     Hello world
3     Hello world
4     Hello world
5     Hello world
6     Hello world
7     Hello world
8     Hello world
9     Hello world
10     Hello world
11     Hello world
12     Hello world
13     Hello world
14     Hello world
15     Hello world
16     Hello world
17     Hello world
18     Hello world
19     Hello world
20     Hello world
```

Comment: Then it will work normaly I want to use 5 Thread

Comment: I don't understand, do you want this https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#with-locks ? You need to edit your question because most people want to have good input when giving a good answer ... my answers are for the developer community not just for the questioner.